# how to manually set dark mode on the system Back,Home,Recent bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How do you set 'dark mode' on the "Back Home Recent" navigation bar at the bottom of the display? I want to it to be black with white icons, as one would expect in a dark mode.

In all of the emulators I've tested on, the "Back Home Recent" background is always transparent or has a black background with white icons, which is ideal for me. However, when my Flutter application is running on my Galaxy S9, the "Back Home Recent" background is always white with black icons. In other apps on my S9, for instance Reddit is Fun, this bar remains black with white icons. How can I accomplish this in Flutter?

To simplify testing, I created the following:

```
ThemeData simpleDarkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      foregroundColor: Colors.white70, backgroundColor: Colors.black),
);

ThemeData simpleLightTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      foregroundColor: Colors.black, backgroundColor: Colors.white70),
);
```

Am I missing an attribute in `ThemeData` that controls the color/mode of the "Back Home Recent" bar?

At the root of my app, the widget build begins with

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const String appTitle = "Remember the Netscape";
    final adState = Provider.of<AdState>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      theme: simpleDarkTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
...
```

Flutter Doctor is as follows. I switched to Channel `master` because of a bug in `stable` causing flickers when navigating between widgets with `google_mobile_ads`. The issue I am having with theming occurs on `stable` as well.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.9.0-1.0.pre.457, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.434], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Sidebar: What is the "Back Home Recent" navigation bar even called? Is there a technical term that I am missing? It wasn't fun to call it that throughout this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution. The "Back Home Recent" bar I was referring to is found in `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle`. To change the color, I simply had to import package:flutter/services.dart then use `setSystemUIOverlayStyle` to change the color. I added a check for Android using dart:io, but I still need to determine if android version 8 or above is in use for compatibility.

Hopefully this helps someone that runs in to the same issue. The process for iOS maybe be similar using the CupertinoNavigationBar.backgroundColor.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:io';


void main() {

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
    ));
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());

...
```